# SQL compare the incremental difference from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table with the columns `CurrentDateTime` and `CurrentValue` where the `CurrentValue` column mostly increments. Sometimes though, the `CurrentValue` resets, this is where the issues start.

So, if it weren't for the reset every now and then, I could just do this:

```
SELECT MAX(CurrentValue)-MIN(CurrentValue) AS AccumulateValue 
FROM Table
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CurrentDateTime), 0);
```

If the `CurrentValue` resets, the `AccumulateValue` is wrong.

Let's say these are the values I got:

```
CurrentDateTime    CurrentValue
-------------------------------
2019-10-01            100
2019-10-02            101
2019-10-03            102
2019-10-04            103
2019-10-05            104
2019-10-06            105
```

This would return 5

But if the values looks like this:

```
CurrentDateTime    CurrentValue
-------------------------------
2019-10-01            100
2019-10-02            101
2019-10-03            102
2019-10-04            103
2019-10-05            104
2019-10-06              0
2019-10-07              1
2019-10-08              2
2019-10-09              3
```

The result would be 101, and it should be 7.

I did try this (calculating the difference between each row and run SUM only on positive values):

```
SELECT SUM(CurrentValue)
FROM
    (SELECT 
         tb1.CurrentDateTime,
         CASE 
            WHEN tb1.CurrentValue > tb1.CurrentValueLag 
               THEN (tb1.CurrentValue - tb1.CurrentValueLag)
            WHEN tb1.CurrentValue <= tb1.CurrentValueLag
               THEN 0
         END AS CurrentValue
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              *,
              LAG(CurrentValue) OVER (ORDER BY CurrentDateTime ASC) AS CurrentValueLag 
          FROM Table) AS tb1) AS tb2
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CurrentDateTime), 0);
```

This table is pretty large with small increments, and the SUM isn't correct for some reason I can't figure out. I noticed when comparing a month (with no reset), the value from this last query shows a higher value than the correct value.

Comment: I added the sql-server tag based on syntax.  Your logic is not not clear.  What is the correct logic when there are "resets"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Thanks for all the help I got.

Apparently, the table also had some corrupted data that made this somewhat messy.
On top of that, the data could also decrease, wich I didn't take into account.

Anyway, I needed to do some Changes to my code, but here it is:

```
SELECT YEAR(CurrentDateTime)
,MONTH(CurrentDateTime)
,SUM(tb2.CurrentValue) AS tb3.CurrentValue
 FROM(
     SELECT tb2.CurrentDateTime
    ,(tb2.CurrentValue - tb2.CurrentValue_LAG) AS CurrentValue --Only do math where there's not NULL.
     FROM(
         SELECT *
         , LAG(tb1.CurrentValue) OVER (ORDER BY tb1.CurrentDateTime ASC) AS 
         CurrentValue_LAG
         FROM(
             SELECT CurrentDateTime
             ,CASE WHEN CurrentValue = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CurrentValue END AS CurrentValue --NULLING the values to exclude them from the tb3 substract operation

             FROM TableOne
             WHERE CurrentDateTime BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
         ) AS tb1
     ) AS tb2
 ) AS tb3
GROUP BY YEAR(CurrentDateTime), MONTH(CurrentDateTime)
```

It might look messy, but it returns the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Doe a simple `WHERE` filter do what you want?

```
SELECT year(CurrentDateTime), month(currentDateTime),
       (MAX(CurrentValue) - MIN(CurrentValue)) AS AccumulateValue
FROM Table
WHERE CurrentValue > 0
GROUP BY year(CurrentDateTime), month(currentDateTime);
```

Comment: Sadly no. I need to calculate the accumulated value. CurrentValue keeps incrementing. Meaning the MIN and MAX value-difference gets to big.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are on the right track by using `lag()`. Then you can do a cumulative sum:

```
select
    sum(case when CurrentValue = CurrentValueLag + 1 then 1 else 0 end) result
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(CurrentValue) over (order by CurrentDateTime) as CurrentValueLag
    from mytable t
) t
group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, CurrentDateTime), 0);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36eb05c50962f67b58c84eebf72182ec)**:

Data:

```
CurrentDateTime     | CurrentValue
:------------------ | -----------:
01/10/2019 00:00:00 |          100
02/10/2019 00:00:00 |          101
03/10/2019 00:00:00 |          102
04/10/2019 00:00:00 |          103
05/10/2019 00:00:00 |          104
06/10/2019 00:00:00 |            0
07/10/2019 00:00:00 |            1
08/10/2019 00:00:00 |            2
09/10/2019 00:00:00 |            3
```

Results:

```
| result |
| -----: |
|      7 |
```

Comment: This doesn't work and gives the same results as Gordons answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2818008: I gave a good second look at your question and edited my answer. This seems to work fine (I added a fiddled to my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (CurrentDateTime DATE,    CurrentValue INT)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES

('2019-10-01', 100),
('2019-10-02', 101),
('2019-10-03', 102),
('2019-10-04', 103),
('2019-10-05', 104),
('2019-10-06',   0),
('2019-10-07',   1),
('2019-10-08',   2),
('2019-10-09',   3)

SELECT MAX(CurrentValue)-MIN(CurrentValue) AS AccumulateValue  FROM (
    SELECT CurrentDateTime, 
    CASE WHEN CurrentValue >= FIRST_VALUE(CurrentValue) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CurrentDateTime), 0) ORDER BY CurrentDateTime)
         THEN CurrentValue
         ELSE MAX(CurrentValue) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CurrentDateTime), 0)) + CurrentValue END AS CurrentValue
    FROM @TempTable
) T
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CurrentDateTime), 0)
```

Result:

```
AccumulateValue
---------------
7
```